# Error: "reducer" is a required argument, and must be a function or an object of functions that can be passed to combineReducers

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

Getting an error with complete white screen and not loading any content on the page.

```
configureStore.ts:167 Uncaught Error: "reducer" is a required argument, and must be a function or an object of functions that can be passed to combineReducers
```

I tried many ways so please help me with it

Comment: Please share your store configuration and reducer files.